# Advantages and disadvantages of using 64-bit build over 32-bit build

Tags: microsoft-windows

For MS-Windows, VIM releases 32-bit executable as well as 64-bit executable. The [VIM download page](https://www.vim.org/download.php#pc) mentions that the 64-bit version uses a lot more memory, but is compatible with 64 bit plugins. Are there any other disadvantages of using the 64-bit version over the 32-bit version? And visa-versa; are there any advantages of using the 64-bit version over the 32-bit version?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! You might want to also look at a StackExchange on Windows or O.S. and ask about 32-bit vs. 64-bit applications there, since I'd expect most answers would apply to Vim same as any other applications. For example: https://superuser.com/questions/271173/how-important-is-having-64-bit-programs-on-64-bit-os and https://superuser.com/questions/662180/whats-the-difference-between-a-32-bit-and-64-bit-program-in-windows

Comment: @filbranden : Thanks.